# AWS API call is being blocked by the CORS policy

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, rest, axios, cors

I created a DynamoDB table and attached 3 lambda functions to it. I'm trying to call these functions by attaching an API Gateway trigger to them. I created a Rest API and then the `get` method. Afterwards, I deployed the API and the  API link works as intended. I'm now trying to call the API using a Axios in React.

```
axios.get("Link")
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  })
```

The problem is that whenever I try to run this on a local server, I get the following error.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I've tried enabling CORS on the API Gateway but that doesn't work either. I know the problem lies somewhere in the backend but I can't figure out what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: Do you have any CORS configured for the lambda / api gateway? Is localhost:3000 one of the allowed domains?

Comment: I do have CORS configured for the API Gateway but I never did anything with localhost.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have enabled CORS then this is expected behaviour. CORS will not allow other domains to access your API unless otherwise configured.

Check how to properly configure CORS on API-Gateway from here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

For your development / test / learning environment you can disable* CORS and then you can call API from localhost.

More troubleshooting on API Gateway CORS issue:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cors-errors/

*It is not recommended based on security grounds

Answer (score -1):

Try opening chrome with CORS security disabled.

Mac OS:

```
open -n -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_test" --disable-web-security
```